# SQL query against all xDB Shard databases

Tags: xdb, sql-database

I am looking for a way on T-SQL to be able to query all the shards at same time.

It looks like Sitecore is using a ShardManager that [is used on code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-shard-map-management), which makes sense for them. But I used SQL a lot to create custom queries to find and validate Sitecore xDB data.

We keep our SQL in Azure, so I am looking into elastic queries. But it seems like a lot of lifting to get there. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-horizontal-partitioning

Comment: Can you use the search index instead? It collects everything together into a single repository. I'm assuming you are avoiding xConnect Search API for a reason?

Comment: xConnect search and the index will not search on the absence of data, like email etc.. So I go right at SQL and get what I need. This is usually just for research and bug issues.

Comment: The main problem you're going to hit is that you can't bridge multiple databases in Azure SQL due to the security implementation.  So a normal union isn't going to work. You need to plumb in an object called an `External Table` or an `External Data Source`.  Check this guide: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126

Comment: Seems like a custom tool would be best, kind of surprised there isn't one as it could be pretty generic where you specify a list of DB's to run the query on.